# Saving custom JSON as custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a datafeed, athat i want to save as a custom post type.

The idea is that based on the users geo location a dynamic header and footer should be rendered with content coming from the feed.

Here is the endpoint to access the data in the fee: https://api.ekstrapoint.com/api/v2/site

I have tried to create a custom post type based on this example.

```
//function for retrieving data from the external API
function fetch_from_ep_api(){
    //make external HTTP request
    $response = wp_remote_get(EP_API_URL);
    if(!empty($response)){
        //handle json
        $parsed_response = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
        $data = json_decode($parsed_response);
        //debug($data)
        //data structure is an array of objects with following attributes
        //print_r($data[0]);
        //$array_response = print_r($parsed_response);

        //debug($array_response);
        return $data;
    }else{
        throw new Exception("Could not connect to EP api");
    }
}

//now i need to create a custom post type to store all the data, but i am in doubt of how to create the custom fields to do so 

function create_custom_ep_country_posttype(){
    $labels = array(
            'name' => __('Countries', 'Post Type country name'),
            'singular_name' => __('Country', 'Post type singular name'),

    );
    $args = array(
            'show_in_admin_bar' => true
    );
    
    register_post_type('country',
    array(

    ));
}
```

I don't understand how the different data types for each attribute maps in the database?

Does anybody have an idea and how to make a custom post type for the data that is in this data feed?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you expected from this? I'm not sure how that feed would become a custom post type, are you expecting multiple posts? You would need to write code to retrieve the JSON from the endpoint, decode it, then process it to create posts. You'd need to run that code at regular intervals, and you'd need a check to confirm if the article already exists to prevent duplication.

Comment: Yes exactly @TomJNowell Let me update the question i have already made the code for fetching the API

Comment: Take a look at `wp_insert_post`, it'll be an important part of any answer written for this question